# Fill the entire area inside a big square (a div) with little squares, based on their quantity

Tags: css, grid, flexbox

I want to solve it just by using css3, maybe with flexbox or grid or some other similar framework.

My markup:

```
<div class="square">
  <div class="smaller-square">
  <div class="smaller-square">
  <div class="smaller-square">
  <div class="smaller-square">
</div>
```

Quantity (Q) of inner boxes I will control. Q = i<sup>2</sup>, where i = 0...N

Comment: Welcome on SO. At least show us something you tried, whether based on Flexbox or Grid layout, with say N=1..3 (1, 4 and 9 smaller squares)

Comment: [Quantity queries](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-sass-quantity-queries/) are close to what you want to achieve

Comment: I've created CodePen to explain it more clearly. Please read comment in CodePen js section. [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/sns_nazar/pen/bwyQJP)

Answer (score 0):

**Updated version:**

As you are taking input from user, get the value of input tag using every time, when its value changed using **onchange** event.

**HTML:**

```
<input onchange="fillSquare()" id="quantity"  type="number" min="0"/> //You can use any input type
```

**Javascript:**

```
function fillSquare(){
   var Q = $("#quantity").val();
   var i = Math.sqrt(Q); // Here I'm taking square root of 'Q' to calculate width and height of small sqaures.
   $('.smaller-square').css({
     "width": (100% / i),
     "height": (100% / i)
   });
}
```

**Old solution:**

I think **calc** property in **CSS** better suits for your requirement.

first of all make sure you've some css like below, to make them blocks.

```
.square{
   display:block;
   width: 500px; //Any number is fine, until both height and width are same
   height: 500px; //Make sure you've some numbers here, as we are going to deal with width and height of smaller-square in percentages
}
.smaller-square{
   display:inline-block;
   float:left;
}
```

Now you can achieve this in two ways, One is in pure **CSS** (the one you asked) and also using some **Javascript** library.

**First, CSS:**

```
.smaller-square{
   width:calc(100% / i);
   height:calc(100% / i);
}
```

Here you have to hard-code **i** value, which means you know **i** value before executing the code. 
Eg., If **i=2** then,

```
.smaller-square{
   width:calc(100% / 2);
   height:calc(100% / 2);
}
```

width and height of **.smaller-square** are **50%** of **.square** width and height.

Comment: Hello, your solution is very close to what I need. Thank you. BUT it lacks very important moment - hardcoding i value. It should be square root of quantity of .smaller-square`s in .square. So it should be dynamic value. Maybe you have an idea how to do it (count smaller-square`s)?

Comment: Please tell me, How do you decide the quantity(Q)? Are you hard-coding or taking it from javascript?

Comment: I`am taking it from javascript. To be more particular from user(using select tag), than I fill .square with .smaller-square(s)

Comment: Then you can go with Javascript function on change of select tag input., as you can't decide css properties like width and height without javsscipt functionality. If you are ok with this, I'll give you modified solution.

Comment: Yes, am okey with it.

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: Thank you for persistance. But solution is still not appropriate for me. I've created CodePen to explain it clearly. Please read comment in CodePen js section. [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/sns_nazar/pen/bwyQJP)